# why i am getting this error request for member set in b which is of non class type box[5]

Tags: c++, class, oop, definition

why I am getting this request for member set in b which is of non class type box[5]?

I am calculating volume of box and storing length breadth and volume in box array of objects

what can I do to solve this?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class box
{
    int length;
    int breadth;
    int height;
    int n;
    int volume;
    box *b;

public:
    box()
    {

    }
    void set(int n)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {this->b=new box[5];
            int len,bre,hei,vol;
            cout<<"enter length"<<endl;
            cin>>len;
            cout<<"enter breadth"<<endl;
            cin>>bre;
            cout<<"enter height"<<endl;
            cin>>hei;
            cout<<"enter volume"<<endl;
            cin>>vol;
            b[i].length=len;
            b[i].breadth=bre;
            b[i].height=hei;
            b[i].volume=vol;
        }
    }
    void get()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<"length "<<b[i].length;
            cout<<"breadth "<<b[i].breadth;
            cout<<"height "<<b[i].height;
            cout<<"volume "<<b[i].volume;
        }
    }

};
int main()
{
   box b[5];
   b.set(5);
   b.get();

}
```

Comment: You never seem to initialise `b` within the context of `box` meaning that `b` points to some garbage address (or `nullptr` cant remember if there is a default init in this case), meaning that a lot within `set`/`get` is UB. Also hard to see due to formatting

Comment: `b.set(5);` in `main`. `b` is an array. arrays dont have member functions

Comment: what did you expect to happen when you wrote `b.set(5);`  and `b.get();` ?

Comment: i want to store length breadth height and volume in box class array of object when i wrote b.set(5); and b.get();

Comment: not the compiler error, but the member `box *b;` is just a pointer. In the member methods you pretend that it points to an array but it doesnt

Comment: @drescherjm there is a member called `b` that was lost in poor formatting

Comment: Are you linking boxes together?  Usually that is the purpose of `box * b;` in a class or struct.  Or maybe you want a collection, of boxes (outside of the box class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*emphasized text*The variable b declared in main

```
box b[5];
```

has an array type. Arrays do not have member functions. So this statement

```
b.set(5);
```

is incorrect. You could write for example

```
b[0].set( 5 );
```

However within the member function set there is used uninitialized pointer `b`

```
        b[i].length=len;
        b[i].breadth=bre;
        b[i].height=hei;
        b[i].volume=vol;
```

that invokes undefined behavior.

So your code as is just does not make a sense.

It seems you need a static member function like for example

```
static void set(box b[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int len,bre,hei,vol;
        cout<<"enter length"<<endl;
        cin>>len;
        cout<<"enter breadth"<<endl;
        cin>>bre;
        cout<<"enter height"<<endl;
        cin>>hei;
        cout<<"enter volume"<<endl;
        cin>>vol;
        b[i].length=len;
        b[i].breadth=bre;
        b[i].height=hei;
        b[i].volume=vol;
    }
}
```

And call it like

```
box b[5];
box::set( b, 5 );
```

In this case you should remove the data members b and n

```
int n;
box *b;
```

in the class definition.

The function get can be declared and defined the following way

```
void get() const
{
    cout<<"length "<< length << '\n';
    cout<<"breadth "<< breadth << '\n';
    cout<<"height "<< height << '\n';
    cout<<"volume "<< volume << '\n';
}
```

And for the declared array in main the function can be called the following way

```
for ( const auto &item : b )
{
    item.get();
    cout << '\n';
}
```